# Fail SQL query if there is at least one wrong record in any of 3 tables (wrong means rate column<=0)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have 3 tables and I need to check if they have a positive number in the "rate" column.
Tables have different schema but they all have a column named "rate".
I am working with airflow and I created a DAG which has a task to check if the rate in not a positive number then fail.
So in a simple word, I want my SQL fails if there is an incorrect rate in any of those tables.
I have done this:

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT deliverydate, rate
  FROM table1
  WHERE rate <= 0
),
t2 AS (
  SELECT deliverydate, rate
  FROM table2
  WHERE rate <= 0
),
t3 AS (
  SELECT deliverydate, rate
  FROM table3
  WHERE rate <= 0
)
SELECT 1 FROM (
  SELECT * FROM t1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM t2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM t3
)
```

In this case, t1, t2 and t3 will report rows with wrong rate(0 or negative rates). And Select 1 fails if there is no wrong rate.

But my goal is: ***pass if all the rates are correct and fail if at least one record has wrong rate and show me that record to fix it.***

SQL queries run on bigquery standard

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, explain what you want for the results.  A value that indicates passing versus failing?  Some sort of error (which `select` generally is not used for)?  1 row for failure and 0 rows for success?

Comment: @GordonLinoff bigquery standard sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest logic like this:

```
select (case when exists (select 1 from table1 where rate <= 0) then 'FAIL'
             when exists (select 1 from table2 where rate <= 0) then 'FAIL'
             when exists (select 1 from table3 where rate <= 0) then 'FAIL'
             else 'PASS'
        end)
```

This stops at the first failure and should be pretty efficient.  For added performance, include an index on `rate` in each of the subtables.

Some databases require a `from` clause, such as `from dual`.

I doubt this is the best way to do things, but this should generate an error only when there is an error condition using [`error()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#error):

```
select (case when exists (select 1 from table1 where rate <= 0) then error('Bad rate in table1')
             when exists (select 1 from table2 where rate <= 0) then error('Bad rate in table2')
             when exists (select 1 from table3 where rate <= 0) then error('Bad rate in table3')
             else 'PASS'
        end)
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. I don't want to get FAIL and PASS words. I want to actually the query fails or pass. Fail means e.g. if you have an empty table and you run select 1 from table; then it fails and pass means the query runs successfully and return some rows which you queried.

Comment: @Saba . . . Seems odd to use an *error* from a `select` for this purpose.  I would rather use the return value.  But you can use the `error()` function in BigQuery.

Comment: thank you for your effort to answer my question. In the first piece of code  there will be always a result, fail or pass. I actually want to run this query as an airflow task and I need it to fail if at least one target rate is negative. For example if I run this query: SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE age = 1000) after running this query in bigquery because there is no age 1000 in table1 so it shows "This query returned no results.". So it failed. I just want to fail for my task if there is at least one row with rate<=0